# Sort algorithm for list of integers in Haskell with recursion

Tags: list, haskell

I need to sort an integer list on haskell, from smaller to greater numbers, but i dont know where to start.

The recursion syntax is kinda difficult for me

A little bit of help would be great.

Ive done this but it does not solve my problem:

```
ordenarMemoria :: [Int] -> [Int]
ordenarMemoria [] = []
ordenarMemoria (x:y:xs) 
    | y > x = ordenarMemoria (y:xs)
    | otherwise = ordenarMemoria (x:xs)
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an idea for an algorithm to sort the list?

Comment: I know that "Sort" function solves my problem. But i need to do it with recursion. Ive posted what ive done by now

Comment: Can you write a function which given some element, and an ordered list, inserts that element into the list such that the list remains ordered?

Comment: I highly recommend starting with a bottom-up merge sort. In my opinion, that's the most natural comparison-based sorting algorithm for Haskell lists.

Comment: If you're sorting, you [probably shouldn't use lists](http://www.imn.htwk-leipzig.de/~waldmann/etc/untutorial/list-or-not-list/). Even though the base libraries include [Data.List.sort](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:21). Working out an algorithm is a useful exercise, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You attempt is on the right track for a *bubble sort*, which is a good starting place for sorting.  A few notes:

You handle the cases when the list is empty or has at least two elements (`x` and `y`), but you have forgotten the case when your list has exactly one element.  You will always reach this case because you are calling your function recursively on smaller lists.

```
ordenarMemoria [x] = -- how do you sort a 1-element list?
```

Second note: in this pattern

```
ordenarMemoria (x:y:xs) 
    | y > x = ordenarMemoria (y:xs)
    | otherwise = ordenarMemoria (x:xs)
```

you are sorting a list starting with two elements `x` and `y`.  You compare `x` to `y`, and then sort the rest of the list after removing one of the two elements.  This is all good.

The question I have is: what happened to the other element?  A sorted list has to have all the same elements as the input, so you should use both `x` and `y` in the output.  So in:

```
    | y > x = ordenarMemoria (y:xs)
```

you have forgotten about `x`.  Consider

```
    | y > x = x : ordenarMemoria (y:xs)
```

which indicates to output `x`, then the sorted remainder.

The other branch forgets about one of the inputs, too.

After you fix the function, you might notice that the list gets a bit more sorted, but it is still not completely sorted.  That's a property of the bubble sort—you might have to run it multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

I'll highly recommend you read *Learn You a Haskell*, there is an online version [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com), it has a [chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion) where you can learn how to sort lists using recursion, like Quicksort for example:

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]  
quicksort [] = []  
quicksort (x:xs) =   
    let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]  
        biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x]  
    in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

Comment: Pedagogical feedback, since you recommended a learning resource: your giving a complete, working code solution as part of your answer vastly decreases the likelihood that the OP will read anything you recommend.

Comment: That's also not a real QuickSort. True QS is not really a good fit for lists. I suppose lists aren't terrible for a "QuickSort" that uses median-of-medians to select pivots, but that's not too quick, is it?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to sort an integer list

How about [`sort` from `Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort)?

```
$ stack ghci
Prelude> :m + Data.List
Prelude Data.List> sort [2,3,1]
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: See the second comment on the question

Comment: @luqui: Thanks, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of choices. I generally recommend starting with bottom-up mergesort in Haskell, but heapsort isn't a bad choice either. Quicksort poses much more serious difficulties.

```
-- Given two lists, each of which is in increasing
-- order, produce a list in increasing order.
--
-- merge [1,4,5] [2,4,7] = [1,2,4,4,5,7]
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] ys = ???
merge xs [] = ???
merge (x : xs) (y : ys)
  | x <= y = ???
  | otherwise = ???

-- Turn a list of elements into a list of lists
-- of elements, each of which has only one element.
--
-- splatter [1,2,3] = [[1], [2], [3]]
splatter :: [a] -> [[a]]
splatter = map ????

-- Given a list of sorted lists, merge the adjacent pairs of lists.
-- mergePairs [[1,3],[2,4],[0,8],[1,2],[5,7]]
--   = [[1,2,3,4],[0,1,2,8],[5,7]]
mergePairs :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [[a]]
mergePairs [] = ????
mergePairs [as] = ????
mergePairs (as : bs : more) = ????

-- Given a list of lists of sorted lists, merge them all
-- together into one list.
--
-- mergeToOne [[1,4],[2,3]] = [1,2,3,4]
mergeToOne :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
mergeToOne [] = ???
mergeToOne [as] = ???
mergeToOne lots = ??? -- use mergePairs here

mergeSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
mergeSort as = ???? -- Use splatter and mergeToOne
```

Once you've filled in the blanks above, try optimizing the sort by making `splatter` produce sorted lists of two or perhaps three elements instead of singletons.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified either quicksort or insertion sort. It uses the fastest method of prefixing or suffixing values to the output list. If the next value is less than or greater than the first or last of the list, it is simply affixed to the beginning or end of the list. If the value is not less than the `head` value or greater than the `last` value then it must be inserted. The insertion is the same logic as the so-called quicksort above.

Now, the kicker. This function is made to run as a `foldr` function just to reduce the complexity of the the function. It can easily be converted to a recursive function but it runs fine with `foldr`.

```
f2x :: (Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
f2x n ls
   | null ls = [n]
   | ( n <= (head ls) ) = n:ls -- ++[11]
   | ( n >= (last ls) ) = ls ++ [n] -- ++ [22]
   | True = [lx|lx <-ls,n > lx]++ n:[lx|lx <-ls,n < lx]
```

The comments after two line can be removed and the function can be run with `scanr` to see how many hits are with simple prefix or suffix of values and which are inserted somewhere other that the first or last value.

```
foldr f2x [] [5,4,3,2,1,0,9,8,7,6]
```

Or `af = foldr a2x []` ... `af [5,4,3,2,1,0,9,8,7,6]` >-> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

**EDIT 5/18/2018**

The best thing about **Stack Overflow** is the people like @dfeuer that make you think. @dfeuer suggested using `partition`. I am like a child, not knowing how. I expressed my difficulty with `partition` but @dfeuer forced me to see how to use it. @dfeuer also pointed out that the use of `last` in the above function was wasteful. I did not know that, either.

The following function uses `partition` imported from `Data.List`.
`partition` outputs a tuple pair. This function is also meant to use with `foldr`. It is a complete insertion sort function.

```
ft nv ls = b++[nv]++e where (b,e) = partition (<=nv) ls
```

Use it like above

```
foldr ft [] [5,4,3,2,1,0,9,8,7,6]
```

Haskell and functional programming is all about using existing functions in other functions.

Comment: Why not use `partition`? Also, the partial functions are unfortunate, and calculating `last` every time seems pretty expensive.

Comment: `partition` works on ordered lists, that is, the predicate does. The input is unordered. What is most interesting to me is how to get `fst` and `snd` from one instance of a tuple pair, not `fst` *pair* and `snd` *pair*. How to make each use one instance, only. Fusion? `last` is expensive, keeping track of first and last each time is less expensive? IDK. Oh, and this is a `foldr` function. More parameters to pass the first and last would increase the complexity.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean at all. `partition` doesn't care what predicate you use. I generally don't understand what you mean about the rest either.

Comment: Hey, my bad. It just tried it and it does without an ordered list. You, again, are so right about everything.I just fell in love with `partition`.But the problem remains how to get the `fst` and `snd` without partitioning twice.

Comment: Why would you have to partition twice? Use `let` or `case`.

Comment: To insert the new value into the constructed list. The new value does not belong at the the beginning or end. `[a,b,c] ++ [nv] ++ [x,y,z]`. A left side and a right side with the new value inserted in between. `fst partition (<=nv) *tuple* ++ [nv] ++ snd partition (>nv) (*tuple*`

Comment: `case partition (<= nv) ls of (beginning, end) -> beginning ++ [nv] ++ end`.

Comment: Genius. This has bothered me for quite some time.

Answer (score -1):

```
putEleInSortedListA :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
putEleInSortedListA a [] = [a]
putEleInSortedListA a (b:bs)
  | a < b     = a : b : bs
  | otherwise = b: putEleInSortedListA a bs

sortListA :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
sortListA la = foldr (\a b -> putEleInSortedListA a b) [] la
```